# Converting pcre REGEX into ICU REGEX in R

Tags: r, regex, pcre, icu

Hello I would like advice on how to convert PCRE REGEX to ICU REGEX so I can use with the R function str_match_all (part of the stringr package).

@Wiktor Stribiżew was able to produce REGEX PCRE parsing as seen in these REGEX101 demos:

https://regex101.com/r/m4UD0j/17

This parses captures aa and bb combos (each preceded by any digit of any length) then cc group(s) (preceded similarly by by digit(s)) e.g. *10aa5bb6bb3bb6aa999cc998cc997cc*

So think of the string as two parts:

The first is a random collection of aa or bb combos (although this might just be all aa, for example) preceded by a digit.

The second half is a series of cc's (although this might just be one cc, for example) preceded by a digit.

It is important that both 'sides' of the string are captured together and both the text and digit are captured specifically. So valid captures are, for example:

```
2aa2cc
323233aa21212bb4555cc
1aa2aa3aa4aa5aa6aa117cc8cc
1bb2bb3bb4bb5bb6bb117cc8cc
1aa2bb3bb4aa5bb6bba117cc8cc
1aa2bb3bb4aa5bb6bba117cc8ccXXXXXXXXXX1aa2bb3bb4aa5bb6bba117cc8cc
```

Invalid:

```
2aa *Only one side of the string is there*
1aa2bb3bb4aa *Only one side of the string is there*
99cc100cc *Only one side of the string is there*
```

Also, I'd like a separate REGEX expression for instances where the 'cc' groups come first in the string e.g. 999cc998cc997cc10aa5bb6bb3bb6aa. This is demonstrated here: https://regex101.com/r/m4UD0j/18

***NOTE: The text patterns aa, bb, & cc are actually abbreviations of longer character strings, so should be treated as such. I provided shorter versions to avoid a more confusing example.***

The two demos show the regex for the different orders of combos.

Now I have to make this run in R using **str_match_all** which unfortunately uses ICU regex, not the pcre regex which we tested in REGEX101.

So I have this code, which throws a **Use of regexp feature that is not yet implemented. (U_REGEX_UNIMPLEMENTED)** error:

```
#REGEX TEST#
library(stringr)

regex_text_1 <- "8aa9aa10bb1cc2cc3cc"
#reg_pattern_1 that worked in REGEX101 <- "(?:\G(?!^)(?(?=\d+(?:aa|bb))(?<!\dcc))|(?=(?:\d+(?:aa|bb))+(?:\d+cc)+))(\d+)(aa|bb|cc)"
reg_pattern_1 <- "(?:\\G(?!^)(?(?=\\d+(?:aa|bb))(?<!\\dcc))|(?=(?:\\d+(?:aa|bb))+(?:\\d+cc)+))(\\d+)(aa|bb|cc)"

regex_text_2 <- "1cc2cc3cc8aa9bb10bb"
#reg_pattern_2 that worked in REGEX101 <- "(?:\G(?!^)(?(?=\d+cc)(?<!\d(?:aa|bb)))|(?=(?:\d+cc)+(?:\d+(?:aa|bb))+))(\d+)(aa|bb|cc)"
reg_pattern_2 <- "(?:\\G(?!^)(?(?=\\d+cc)(?<!\\d(?:aa|bb)))|(?=(?:\\d+cc)+(?:\\d+(?:aa|bb))+))(\\d+)(aa|bb|cc)"

sm <- str_match_all(regex_text_1, reg_pattern_1)
sm.df <- as.data.frame(sm)
print(sm.df)

sm <- str_match_all(regex_text_2, reg_pattern_2)
sm.df <- as.data.frame(sm)
print(sm.df)
```

I'd actually like it to output something like this:

```
    X1 X2 X3
1  8aa  8 aa
2  9aa  9 aa
3 10bb 10 bb
4 1cc  1 cc
5 2cc  2 cc
6 3cc  3 cc
```

and

```
    X1 X2 X3
1 1cc  1 cc
2 2cc  2 cc
3 3cc  3 cc
4  8aa  8 aa
5  9aa  9 aa
6 10bb 10 bb
```

...as it would if we applied it in pcre.

I am not expert enough to convert the code from pcre to icu so would really appreciate some help. Many thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this does not convert to ICU, but is even better. It is a Perl version of STR_MATCH_ALL. It works beautifully.

Thanks to whoever built it. It came from here:

[str_match_all_perl](https://rdrr.io/github/tdhock/plotMakefile/src/R/regex.R)

```
### Parse several occurances of pattern from each of several strings
### using (named) capturing regular expressions, returning a list of
### matrices (with column names).
str_match_all_perl <- function(string,pattern){
  stopifnot(is.character(string))
  stopifnot(is.character(pattern))
  stopifnot(length(pattern)==1)
  parsed <- gregexpr(pattern,string,perl=TRUE)
  lapply(seq_along(parsed),function(i){
    r <- parsed[[i]]
    starts <- attr(r,"capture.start")
    if(r[1]==-1)return(matrix(nrow=0,ncol=1+ncol(starts)))
    names <- attr(r,"capture.names")
    lengths <- attr(r,"capture.length")
    full <- substring(string[i],r,r+attr(r,"match.length")-1)
    subs <- substring(string[i],starts,starts+lengths-1)
    m <- matrix(c(full,subs),ncol=length(names)+1)
    colnames(m) <- c("",names)
    m
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind,regmatches(a<-strsplit(regex_text_1,'(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])',perl = T)[[1]],regexec('(\\d)(\\D+)',a))))
   X1 X2 X3
1 8aa  8 aa
2 9aa  9 aa
3 0bb  0 bb
4 1cc  1 cc
5 2cc  2 cc
6 3cc  3 cc
```

or in many steps:

```
a = strsplit(regex_text_1, '(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])', perl = TRUE)[[1]]
b = regmatches(a, regexec('(\\d)(\\D+)', a))
data.frame(do.call(rbind, b))
   X1 X2 X3
1 8aa  8 aa
2 9aa  9 aa
3 0bb  0 bb
4 1cc  1 cc
5 2cc  2 cc
6 3cc  3 cc
```

You can do the same with `regex_text_2`. If at all you have many of them:

```
 ff = function(x)data.frame(do.call(rbind,regmatches(a<-strsplit(x,'(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])',perl = T)[[1]],regexec('(\\d)(\\D+)',a))))

 ff(regex_text_1)
   X1 X2 X3
1 8aa  8 aa
2 9aa  9 aa
3 0bb  0 bb
4 1cc  1 cc
5 2cc  2 cc
6 3cc  3 cc
ff(regex_text_2)
   X1 X2 X3
1 1cc  1 cc
2 2cc  2 cc
3 3cc  3 cc
4 8aa  8 aa
5 9bb  9 bb
6 0bb  0 bb
```

Also you can use `gsub` and do:

```
transform(read.table(text=gsub('(\\d+)(\\D+)','\\1 \\2\n',regex_text_1)),v3=paste0(V1,V2))
  V1 V2   v3
1  8 aa  8aa
2  9 aa  9aa
3 10 bb 10bb
4  1 cc  1cc
5  2 cc  2cc
6  3 cc  3cc
```

Comment: Hi there. Many thanks. I have edited my question to be more clear. I need it only to capture when the combinations happen together. So _1cc2cc3cc_ on its own will not be picked up. Neither will _8aa9aa10bb_ on its own. And _1cc2cc3ccXXXXXXXXYYYZZZ8aa9aa10bb_   will not work.

Comment: you can use `grep` to capture the specified pattern, ie `^(?=.*aa)(?=.*bb)(?=.*cc)(?!.*[d-z])` to determine that a string has the pattern `aa` bb` cc` and does not have any other letters from `d-z`

Comment: Would this allow 1bb2aa3aa3cc to be parsed and accepted? Also, these letters are not quite the real data but mock data to make the example simpler. In reality, aa represents a specific string which is about 10 chars long.

Comment: Hi @Onyambu, have I complicated matters?